# Google App Script not picking up closing function curly bracket

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using Google App Script to move and set cell values and formats between sheets identified by:

> ss.getSheetByName('MONTHLY')

When I move the closing curly bracket past line 230 it registers as red and does not close.

I have declared variables outside of the functions as well.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for the help!

[image: Closing Curlybracket]

Comment: It's probably a visual bug. It saves and works anyway right?

Comment: It works, I'm new to programming - not sure if I'm doing something wrong. Thanks for the help!